# Add loop to HTML5 audio with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

How would I change this:

```
<audio id ="duck" src="sound.mp3" autoplay ></audio>
```

to this

```
<audio id="duck" src="sound.mp3" autoplay loop></audio>
```

using getElementById ?

Normally I'd use setAttribute but there's no category name here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it using the loop property like so:

```
var audioElement = document.getElementById("duck");
audioElement.loop = true;
```